# CFStringTokenizer's token range in a UTF8 C string

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-foundation

I'm using CFStringTokenizer to break a load of text into words, but I'm having difficulty bridging whatever encoding CFString is using and UTF8. Consider this:

```
NSString *theString = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!";

const char *theCString = [theString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

tokenizer = CFStringTokenizerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                    (__bridge CFStringRef)theString, 
                                    CFRangeMake(0, [theString length]), 
                                    kCFStringTokenizerUnitWordBoundary, 
                                    locale);

while ((tokenType = CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken(tokenizer)) != kCFStringTokenizerTokenNone) {
    tokenRange = CFStringTokenizerGetCurrentTokenRange(tokenizer);
    memcpy(resultPtr, theCString+tokenRange.location, tokenRange.length);
}
```

Unfortunately the range reported by the tokenizer is incorrect when trying to read from the C string if any non-ascii characters have been encountered. How can I go about getting the correct range from the tokenizer to be able to pull the correct chars from my C string?

To clarify, the memcpy stuff is a tad more complex than above, and is necessary for performance on my target device, the iPhone. So I can't even do anything like create a CFString substring and convert that, I need the range in the C string. Is there any way to do that without reimplementing various word boundary libraries to get it working for the various different locales I need it to work with? (which is as many as possible, so I can't just iterate through looking for ' ' unfortunately..)

Alec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSStrings and CFStrings deal in UTF-16, not UTF-8, but that isn't the real problem.

Your code has two problems:

1. You're assuming that the C string's indexes correspond to the source string's indexes.
2. You're copying and converting the entire string to a UTF-8 C string at once.

#1 is the cause of the range mismatches, and #2 causes potentially high memory usage, depending on the length and content of the string. (UTF-8 can take as many as four bytes per character in some alphabets—and then add one for the C string terminator.)

You can solve both of these problems in a single change.

Create an NSMutableData to hold the output. For each token, set the data's length to the range's `length`; then, tell the string to get bytes within the desired range in the desired encoding and store them in the data's `mutableBytes` buffer. NSString has [a method with a very long selector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getBytes%3amaxLength%3ausedLength%3aencoding%3aoptions%3arange%3aremainingRange%3a) (briefly, `getBytes:::::::`) that you will want to use for this.

Since you use the range that is relative to the string exclusively with the string, there is no index/range mismatch, and each token will be output correctly.

If you really need a C string, you can set the data's length to the range's `length` + 1, then set the last byte to `'\0'` with a separate assignment after getting the token bytes. (Without the separate assignment, the byte may hold a previous value.)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I've got it using getBytes now and the range issue's sorted. I wanted to avoid a method like that however as it adds so much overhead on the iPhone, it's now taking about 60% of the time in this algorithm, and the rest of the work isn't exactly trivial. Unfortunately there's no "NoCopy" variant of getBytes (that I'm aware of?) so I'm thinking I've reached the end of the road with regards to optimisation..

Comment: @Alec: You may want to ask another question about that that shows what you intend to do with the UTF-8 data.